# Find all the tables a view depends on

Tags: oracle, view, dependencies

I have got an Oracle VIEW and I would like to find all the tables my view depends on.
Possibly, my view depends on other view: in this case, I would like to recursively navigate the dependencies and get to the tables.

Here is an example of my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (A NUMBER);
CREATE TABLE T2 (B NUMBER);
CREATE TABLE T3 (A NUMBER, B NUMBER);

CREATE VIEW V1 AS SELECT * FROM T1;
CREATE VIEW V2 AS SELECT * FROM T2;
CREATE VIEW V3 AS SELECT * FROM V1, V2 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM T3;
```

And this is the output I would like to get:

```
VIEW_NAME TABLE NAME
--------- ----------
V3        T1
V3        T2
V3        T3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DBA/USER/ALL_DEPENDENCIES system view has this information. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1066.htm#i1576452

You can query it recursively using a CONNECT BY clause in the SELECT

Comment: You need dba privileges for this.

Comment: @Rachcha select_catalog_role is enough, except perhaps for dba_dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

Solved with David Aldridge's answer. I used the following query:

```
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.name AS view_name, d.referenced_name AS table_name
FROM user_dependencies d
WHERE d.referenced_type = 'TABLE'
START WITH d.name = 'V3' AND d.type = 'VIEW'
CONNECT BY PRIOR d.referenced_name = d.name AND PRIOR d.referenced_type = d.type
```